# Execute a PHP code on JS application

Tags: javascript, php

I want to develop a app that controls the volume of my LG Smart TV. I stumbled upon [this repo](https://github.com/SteveWinfield/PHP-LG-SmartTV).
Upon researching deeply about PHP, I set up my PC (the only place I will use the app) with WAMP Server. I have a couple of JS files and is displayed by HTML file the do some detection work.

So each time the detection is done (I call it a tick), I want a suitable action (Up Volume, Down volume, No Change). So I want the code to be executed when the JS Event of increasing and decreasing volume is executed. Can you help me?

EDIT:- I want to run 2 different PHP files depending upon the action suitable for the tick.

Comment: Far too broad a question....need to narrow this down to specific code related issues. Also look through the help center regarding what to ask/what not to ask and how to put good questions together. Will get lots of help once you narrow down to specifics

Comment: You need to run PHP on your PC web server, so that when AJAX calls your PHP, you connect to your TV using this library, send the command, and disconnect. Have you got an AJAX call working? You can do this in raw JavaScript, but I prefer to use a library like jQuery - I think it is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax call to a php file, no other way. You should understand that JS is client side language, but PHP is serverside language (executes on server and you just receive the code generated by the PHP). PHP file will be executed serverside, but the request will be made by your JS function and you will receive the result of execution at the end of the ajax call so you can do something with your JS code depending on the result.

Comment: If someone votes down, at least he should explain quickly his vote.

Comment: If someone votes down, she is perfectly at liberty not to explain her vote.

Comment: Can you reply with the code. I am just a beginner in web development (Yes, I am a native app dev (C#)). I usually only do Small jQueries, JS, Intermediate CSS and HTML. But I will still Google it out.

Comment: we are not at war @halfer, we are discussing a problem, if you or somone else have some reasons to think that an answer is incorrect or improper, let us see what are his/her reasons and we may find a better solution.

Comment: The community is predominantly of the view that downvotes _may_ be explained, but that an explanation is not mandatory: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/472495

Comment: Community - means people with a common idea in our case to help eachother solving different kind of problems. Of course it is not a mandatory but the idea of giving better solutions requires communication b/w people and I personally think that there should be a bit of respect for those guys who spend their free time to help other for free. They do it not for money, but for a bit of respect.

Comment: FWIW, I sympathise with the issue, and I try to offer advice when I downvote (unless a question is so bad it's not worth the effort, or someone has already explained the problem).

Comment: Okay, I tried it out and worked. But in my case, I just ran a XmlHttpRequest. Thank you anyways